# Текст цитаты обрывается

Tags: javascript, html, css

Проблема в том, что длинные цитаты обрываются на 66м знаке. Вообще нет догадок, что может оказаться причиной. Заранее извиняюсь, если код окажется тяжелочитаемым/неупорядоченным - первые попытки...

Вот ссылка на мою работу в codepen: https://codepen.io/OrcinusOrca/pen/erzGzL
js

```
var alphabet = ["Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O", "P", "A", "S", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L", "Z", "X", "C", "V", "B", "N", "M", "'", ".", ",", "!", "?", " ", ">", "<", "_", "-"];

var quotes = [
  {quote: "LIFE ISN'T ABOUT FINDING YOURSELF, LIFE IS ABOUT CREATING YOURSELF", author: "GEORGE BERNARD SHOW"},
  {quote: "IF YOU CAN DREAM IT, YOU CAN DO IT", author: "WALT DISNEY"},
  {quote: "THE SUCCESSFUL WARRIOR IS THE AVERAGE MAN, WITH LASER-LIKE FOCUS", author: "BRUCE LEE"},
  {quote: "IF YOU REALLY LOOK CLOSELY, MOST OVERNIGHT SUCCESSES TOOK A LONG TIME", author: "STEVE JOBS"},
  {quote: "KEEP YOUR FACE ALWAYS TOWARD THE SUNSHINE - AND SHADOWS WILL FALL BEHIND YOU", author: "WALT WHITMAN"},
  {quote: "LET US MAKE OUR FUTURE NOW, AND LET US MAKE OUR DREAMS TOMORROW’S REALITY", author: "MALALA YOUSAFZAI"},
  {quote: "IT IS ALWAYS THE SIMPLE THAT PRODUCES THE MARVELOUS", author: "AMELIA BARR"},
  {quote: "ALL YOU NEED IS THE PLAN, THE ROAD MAP, AND THE COURAGE TO PRESS ON TO YOUR DESTINATION", author: "EARL NIGHTINGALE"},
  ];

var typeButton;

function addButtons () {
  let buttonBlock = document.getElementById("button-block");
  for (var i=0; i < 36; i++) {
  typeButton = document.createElement("div");
  typeButton.classList.add("type-button");
  typeButton.id = ("type-button" + alphabet[i]);
  typeButton.innerHTML = alphabet[i];
  buttonBlock.appendChild(typeButton);       
      }
  }
addButtons();

  var result = "";
  var j = 0;
  var textArea = document.getElementById("text-area");
  var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*quotes.length);


function newQuote () {
  var quoteLetter = quotes[rnd].quote[j];
  var activeButton = document.getElementById("type-button" + quoteLetter);

  activeButton.style.boxShadow = "none";
  activeButton.style.margin = "4px 2px 0 2px";

  setTimeout(function () {
  activeButton.style.backgroundColor = "#DBD7CF";
    result += quoteLetter;
    textArea.innerHTML = result;
    j += 1;
    if (j<quotes[0].quote.length) {
      activeButton.style.boxShadow = "-2px 3px 3px grey";
      activeButton.style.margin = "2px";
      newQuote();
    }
   }, 50)
  }
var authorArea = document.getElementById("author");
authorArea.innerHTML = "Made by <span>Alexander Yanichev</span>";
var buttonGet = document.getElementById("getQuote");

  buttonGet.onclick = function getQuote () {
  rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*quotes.length);
  var authorName = quotes[rnd].author;
  authorArea.innerHTML = authorName;
  result = "";
  j = 0;
  var textArea = "";
  newQuote ();
  activeButton.style.boxShadow = "-2px 3px 3px grey";   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замените:

```
if (j<quotes[0].quote.length) {
```

на

```
if (j<quotes[rnd].quote.length) {
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Скажите, пожалуйста, еще есть такой эффект, как умножение скорость выведения текста при многократном нажатии на кнопку. При этом цитаты, бывает, обрываются. Можно этого как-то избежать? Может ли помочь clearInterval?

Comment: Попробуйте [задать другой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Думаю, что лучше блокировать нажатие пока выводится цитата.